# Problem in using fncychap and xepersian packages

Tags: book-design, xepersian, fncychap

I want to use a different style for the book document class. I found out that I have to use fncychap package with an option. Since I'm using the xepersian package, it did not work. How can I have a different book style while I'm using the xepersian package? Here is my code

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Zar}
\setdigitfont{Yas}

\begin{document}

\chapter{
نام فصل
}

\section{
نام بخش
}

این یک متن آزمایشی است.

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you load `fncychap` after `xepersian` it almost works  (there is no chapter name).

Comment: Dear @Javier Bezos, thank you.  It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the @Javier Bezos comment I have found the answer as

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Zar}
\setdigitfont{Yas}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}

\begin{document}

\chapter{
نام فصل
}

\section{
نام بخش
}

این یک متن آزمایشی است.

\end{document}
```